# putting a php variable in a HTML form value

Tags: php, html

I've got a php variable like so.. `$name = $_REQUEST['name'];` I'd like to put it in a HTML form field's value e.g in here.. `<input type="text" name="name" value=(php variable here) />`
How would I do so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name); ?>"
```

Answer (score 10):

You can do it like this,

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>" />
```

But seen as you've taken it straight from user input, you want to sanitize it first so that nothing nasty is put into the output of your page.

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name);?>" />
```

Comment: Short tags are deprecated and that opens up a lovely world of XSS (since $name is clearly indicated as user generated content in the code provided in the question)

Comment: Thanks, I noticed the sanitizing once I'd answered and was already updating when you posted this comment ;) I've updated my answer to remove the short tags after your comment though. I know they're deprecated, but I still use them so it was just automatic to type it out that way.

Comment: That isn't properly sanitized. Quotes are still allowed and you didn't set the character set.