# PHP - Set value in HTML-Form

Tags: php

I'm a PHP-Newbie and want to create a simple Website to manage my CD Collection.

**I connect to a MySQL-Database and create for each table a PHP-Array.**

No i want to be able to edit my CDs within HTML-Forms and submit it back to the MySQL-Database.

**For that i create a for-loop and put each array-varaible into an HTML-Form, so i can edit the text und via submit UPDATE my Database.**

*I know there is an answer for my question: [stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317730/putting-a-php-variable-in-a-html-form-value)*

But this solution didn't work for me.

One line:

```
echo "<input name="Titel" type="text" size="30" value="<?php echo $alben[$i]['Titel']; ?>">";
```

This line doesn't work, an i don't understand why.

Can someone please help?

EDIT:
If i just say:

```
echo $alben[$i]['Titel'];
```

This work. But with the HTML-Form i'm getting this error message:

```
 syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'
```

Comment: What happens if you `print_r($alben[$i])` ?

Comment: i always get the above error message. even with your solution

Comment: What line is that error on?  Maybe the error is elsewhere in the code.

Comment: The Error is for this line. It says the error is in line 26, and this is the line 26. When i comment it, i don't get the message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Because you need escape the quotes and remove the 2nd echo`

```
echo "<input name="Titel" type="text" size="30" value="<?php echo $alben[$i]['Titel']; ?>">";
```

into

```
echo "<input name=\"Titel\" type=\"text\" size=\"30\" value=\"" . $alben[$i]['Titel'] . "\">";
```

period is string concatination
"a" . "b" becomes "ab"

Comment: Woohoo... this works!! Great, thank you! EVERY Tutorial on the internet shows the wrong solution, but this one works.

Answer (score 1):

if you are in php tag use this:

```
<?php
...
echo '<input name="Titel" type="text" size="30" value="'. $alben[$i]['Titel']; .'">"';
..
?>
```

if you are in html, use this:

```
<input name="Titel" type="text" size="30" value="<?php echo $alben[$i]['Titel']; ?>">
```