# how to set array data form in php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to set these array data for the form.

**This is my array.**

```
 Array
    (
        [studentId] => 1
        [lecturerId] => 1
        [lecturerName] => muni
        [studentName] => kali
        [studentUniversityId] => we140
    )
```

**This is my html form. i want set array data as a value for this form.**

```
<form action="" method="post">

        <label for="studentID">Student ID</label>
        <input type="text" name="studentUniversityId" id="studentID" placeholder="studentID">

        <label for="studentName">Student Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="studentName" value="" name="studentName" placeholder="Student Name"><br><br>

        <label for="supervisorName">Supervisor Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="supervisorName" name="lecturerName" placeholder="Supervisor Name"><br><br>   

        <input type="submit" id="Upload" name="submit" value="Upload">
```

Comment: how to set the values of the array to the fields of the form.. my friend. ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [putting a php variable in a HTML form value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317730/putting-a-php-variable-in-a-html-form-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$myArray = array(
    "studentId" => 1
    "lecturerId" => 1
    "lecturerName" => "muni" //add other values
)
```

Add them to "value" attribute of HTML tags.

```
value="<?=$myArray["lecturerName"]?>"
```

Comment: `$info=$_SESSION['supervisor_data'];` I'm getting this array like this. your code not working properly my friend.